# How to load data from multiple flat source files into a single flat file using SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I've around 100 flat files(CSV) in a folder and I need to load them into a single text file. The column structure is same for all the source files and has to be the same in destination as well. I know, using Foreach container in SSIS, it can be done. Tried doing it so but the loop is not running  and only one file data is be loaded into the destination and execution will finish. Please suggest to fix it so that loop runs through all the files in the source folder.

Thanks in advance, Krishna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there are so many articles on looping through files in SSIS, that you should have no problem googling them.

But there's other solution than loops: use Multiple Flat Files manager. If all files have the same format, you just specify list of file paths, or use wildecard characters to filter the files, and you don't need to do anything else (provided that filenames themselves do not contain information you need to extract).

[image: new manager]

[image: multiflatfile]